# Polling: Do Get-Request until result suits

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sleep

I have the following code:

```
$.get( "GetJobResult", { jobId: jobId }, function( answer ) {

})
```

If the "answer" is not "false" I want to wait like 20 seconds and do this request again to check if its now something else than "false".

I found many alike questions but after two hours I still can't figure out how to do that. Main problem is the "sleeping" for 20 seconds. If I dont't do that I get too many recursions if calling a function around the ajax-call when the answer comes.

Like:

```
function doCall( jobId , test) {
   if (test == "false") {
       $.get( "GetJobResult", { jobId: jobId }, function( answer ) {
            // how to wait here?
            doCall( jobId, answer );
        });
    }
}
```

I am a little bit stuck here. Can anyone help me? Thanks alot!

**Edit:**
I already tried setTimeout like this:

```
function doCall( jobId , test) {
       if (test == "false") {
           $.get( "GetJobResult", { jobId: jobId }, function( answer ) {
                setTimeout(
                    doCall( jobId, answer ),
                    20000);
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: setTimeout takes a **function**, not a function call. Since doCall doesn't return anything, that setTimeout line you have evaluates to:

setTimeout(undefined,2000);

Comment: Oh wow, okay I will change and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into using [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)? That's how you would execute a function after waiting X milliseconds. So if you wanted to wait 5 seconds, you would do:

```
setTimeout(function(){ doCall( jobId, answer ); }, 5000)
```

The 5000 there is 5000 milliseconds. Does that help?

Edit: Just to clarify, the first argument in setTimeout has to be a function. So another way you could do this is:

```
setTimeout(doCall,5000)
```

But there's a problem here. setTimeout doesn't know what arguments you want. Instead we can create a new function that calls the doCall with the correct arguments:

```
var delayedCall = function(){
  doCall(jobId,answer)
}
setTimeout(delayedCall,5000)
```

That should work, and that's the same thing as:

```
setTimeout(function(){ doCall( jobId, answer ); }, 5000)
```

Except now we're creating a nameless function and passing it in at the same time.

Comment: I tried this one. But this doesn't help. At least not the way I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.time` (non-standard)

```
console.time('someFunction');

someFunction(); // run whatever needs to be timed in between the statements

console.timeEnd('someFunction');
```

**Note:** 
The string being pass to the `time()` and `timeEnd()` methods must match
(for the timer to finish as expected).

Let me know if that was the question :)